# Uneven distribution of particles on a mesh

Tags: modeling

I have a slight problem, that is, I attributed particles to the vertices of my mesh but in some areas, particles do not show off. I do not understand why it is like that, perhaps you could help me.

Thank you.

[image]
geometry :
[image]